# Is there easier way to find free disk space in a script than 'df'?

Tags: disk-usage, tmpfs

I need to find amount of free disk space on a RAM disk in a portable script (not GUI, not anything distro-specific). The df utility does the job, but it spews quite a lot of output so I have to fish it out, like:

```
df -P /tmp | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4; }'
```

Tried also `stat` but cannot figure how to specify a 'filesystem' to it. Even when tmpfs is mounted on /tmp, `stat "%f" /tmp` interprets /tmp as a file, not as a filesystem.

Is there a better way?

(No this is not a duplicate for 'how to find  free disk space and analyze usage'. Thank you for being so vigilant)

Comment: The way you do it is the way to go. You've a oneliner that does what you need (with only 3 commands), not sure why you look for a shorten way.

Comment: Thanks @Vinny. I'm not expert in Unix, thought there's something obvious I'm missing. And would like to minimize dependency on  other things (tail,awk).

Comment: For the filesystem information on `/tmp`, use `stat -f /tmp`.  You'd still need some massaging of the output if you want a single number.

Comment: A compatible way would be to use `read -d '' -ra df_arr < <(LC_ALL=C df -P /tmp); echo "${df_arr[11]}"` See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/094?highlight=%28disk%29

Comment: @ddbug I think your solution is good, simple and readable. You should stick to it. with `stat -f /tmp` you still need to do manipulations, `stat -f /tmp | grep 'Free' | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $5 }'`. Looks less efficient if you ask me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page for `stat(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)

> **-f, --file-system**
>       display file system status instead of file status

So to pull the free blocks of the filesystem on which `/tmp` is located, you could try something like

```
stat -f /tmp -c "%f"
```

Or, to get the value in octets, multiply free blocks by blocksize:

```
stat -f /tmp -c "%f*%S" | bc
```

Comment: Perfect! except that bc is not available on my system ,so `echo $(( $(stat -f /tmp -c "%f*%S") ))`